# Plotting the pair correlation function for the zeta zeros /GUE

Tags: mathematical-physics, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions, random-matrices

I am making a shameless request for instructions on how to plot this:

[image]

from [this page](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/chance_news/recent_news/primes_part3/part3.html). I can see from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery%27s_pair_correlation_conjecture) that normalizing the zeros is given by $\delta(n)=(\gamma_{n+1}-\gamma_{n})\dfrac{\log(\gamma_{n}/2\pi)}{2\pi},$ where $\gamma_{n}=\Im\ n$th zeta zero. I cannot, for the life of me however, seem to fathom how to plot its corresponding pair correlation.

To plot this

[image]

would be an added bonus, but I can't find the reference to 4.19 anywhere.

Any information on how to plot the pair correlation for random Hermitian matrices, given by something like

```
n = 100; m = # + ConjugateTranspose[#] &@RandomComplex[{0, 1 + I}, {n, n}];
h = ReplacePart[m[[#]], # -> RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 1][[1]]] & /@ Range@n;
HermitianMatrixQ[h]
h // MatrixForm;
```

would be welcomed also!

Comment: I am also puzzled by these kinds of plots.  I guess you may need to calculate the distribution of the pair distance $\delta(j)-\delta(i)$ for all $1\le i \lt j \le 10000$ as a function of $j-i$.

Comment: Please see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49172/calculating-the-density-of-nearest-neighbours).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the heads up!